# converting daily data temperature into months in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to convert 10 years(1991-2000) daily data temperature into months in pandas using python 2.7. I have taken the data from the web page ("http://owww.met.hu/eghajlat/eghajlati_adatsorok/bp/Navig/201j_EN.htm"). But I have got a trouble. The data looks as follows:

```
    ` datum  d_ta  d_tx  d_tn  d_rs d_rf  d_ss
---------- ----- ----- ----- ----- ---- -----
1991-01-01   3.0   5.4   1.5   0.2 1      0.0
1991-01-02   4.0   7.2   1.9   0.0 1      6.8
1991-01-03   6.0   8.8   3.6   0.0 1      2.5
1991-01-04   3.7   7.6   2.3    .         2.9
1991-01-05   4.9   7.2   1.5    .         0.0
1991-01-06   2.7   6.2   0.5    .         0.9
1991-01-07   4.0   8.4   1.9    .         3.2
1991-01-08   6.7   8.9   4.6   0.0 0      0.0
1991-01-09   4.1   8.0   3.0   0.3 0      0.0
1991-01-10   4.2   8.1   2.4   0.0 0      0.2
1991-01-11   4.7   6.9   3.6    .         0.7
1991-01-12   7.0   9.8   3.2    .         0.1
1991-01-13   6.3   8.2   4.6    .         0.0
1991-01-14   3.7   6.8   2.2    .         4.7
1991-01-15   0.7   3.4  -1.0    .         7.6
1991-01-16  -1.4   1.4  -3.0    .         7.5
1991-01-17  -2.5   2.1  -5.0    .         8.1
1991-01-18  -1.8   4.0  -5.1    .         7.0
1991-01-19  -3.0   0.1  -4.0    .         5.8
1991-01-20  -2.8   0.5  -5.2    .         5.6
1991-01-21  -5.0  -1.7  -7.8    .         0.0
1991-01-22  -3.3  -1.8  -4.2    .         0.0
1991-01-23  -1.7   0.4  -2.5    .         0.0
1991-01-24   0.0   3.2  -1.6    .         2.2
1991-01-25   1.1   5.1  -0.9    .         6.4
1991-01-26   0.6   4.5  -0.5    .         7.1
1991-01-27  -1.5   2.2  -4.0    .         0.0
1991-01-28   1.3   5.6  -0.8    .         3.8
1991-01-29   0.7   2.6  -0.4    .         1.1
1991-01-30   0.3   4.0  -1.2    .         7.3
1991-01-31  -5.0  -0.2  -7.4    .         8.0
1991-02-01  -8.1  -3.7 -11.7    .         7.6
1991-02-02  -7.0  -2.0 -10.2    .         7.4
1991-02-03  -5.3   0.8  -9.9    .         7.8
1991-02-04  -5.1  -2.3  -7.7   0.1 4      3.7
1991-02-05  -7.5  -4.4  -8.3    .         2.6
1991-02-06  -7.1  -2.2 -11.0   2.0 4      4.9
1991-02-07  -1.8   0.0  -2.7   2.7 4      0.0
1991-02-08  -1.8   0.4  -3.6  21.8 4      0.0
1991-02-09   0.8   2.0  -0.2   1.3 1      0.0
1991-02-10   1.6   3.4  -0.2   3.4 1      0.0
1991-02-11   0.7   2.5  -0.5   1.1 4      0.0
1991-02-12  -0.5   1.2  -1.0   4.7 4      0.0
1991-02-13  -2.0  -0.8  -2.6   0.0 4      0.0
1991-02-14  -1.8   1.4  -3.5   0.1 4      6.3
1991-02-15  -4.2  -0.8  -6.4    .         8.4
1991-02-16  -5.6  -2.4  -9.5   0.1 4      1.5
1991-02-17  -1.3   1.9  -3.8    .         8.3
1991-02-18  -1.3   4.5  -5.5    .         8.5
1991-02-19  -1.5   3.6  -4.7    .         5.8
1991-02-20  -1.4   4.7  -5.4    .         7.3
1991-02-21   1.0   6.1  -2.1    .         6.9
1991-02-22   4.1  10.1   0.5    .         3.2
1991-02-23   5.1   9.7   2.9    .         7.5
1991-02-24   6.0   8.6   5.5   0.0 1      1.8
1991-02-25   3.6   9.2   0.6    .         8.1
1991-02-26   3.9   9.3   1.2    .         2.9
1991-02-27   3.1   6.5   0.3    .         8.8
1991-02-28   1.4   5.3  -2.4    .         4.3
1991-03-01   1.7   3.5  -0.2    .         0.0
1991-03-02   2.4   3.3   1.7   0.8 4      0.0
1991-03-03   3.1   3.8   1.7    .         0.0
1991-03-04   4.3   6.2   2.7    .         1.5
1991-03-05   3.0   5.7   0.6    .         1.2
.........`
```

Somebody please can help me how I can convert it into months. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! If you find a comment or answer helpful, you can help other users by voting on it. If an answer answers your question, you can tick it off to tell other users that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After copying the table into memory starting from the numbers:

```
import pandas, bs4, requests, itertools, io

html = requests.get("http://owww.met.hu/eghajlat/eghajlati_adatsorok/bp/Navig/201j_EN.htm").text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)

# the manual way:
# data = pandas.read_clipboard(names=["datum", "d_ta", "d_tx", "d_tn", "d_rs", "d_rf", "d_ss"], index_col='datum', parse_dates=['datum'])

# the automatic way:
table_html = '\n'.join(itertools.islice(map(lambda _: _.text, soup.find_all("pre")), 3, None))
data = pandas.read_table(io.StringIO(table_html), header=None, sep='\s+', index_col=0, parse_dates=0,
                         names=["datum", "d_ta", "d_tx", "d_tn", "d_rs", "d_rf", "d_ss"])

data.resample('m').mean()
```

You can, of course, use a different aggregation function other than the mean. The output:

```
            d_ta        d_tx        d_tn        d_rf        d_ss
datum                   
1991-01-31  1.345161    4.609677    -0.574194   3.000000    1.583333
1991-02-28  -1.142857   2.592857    -3.639286   5.157143    1.516667
1991-03-31  8.158065    12.093548   5.141935    2.645161    0.775000
1991-04-30  9.920000    14.570000   6.510000    4.066667    4.450000
1991-05-31  13.396774   17.780645   9.738710    4.529032    4.280000
...
```

Comment: @Userabc You complicated this too much. you should 1) read the data on the webpage, 2) coerce that data into a pandas DataFrame; and 3) resample that dataframe into monthly averages. Your question is about #3 and presupposes that #1 and #2 have been handled. This answer solves #3 very efficiently. If you're have trouble with #1 or #2, those are very different questions.

Comment: I edited the question. Now it sounds clear. Still I need hints to start. thanks

Comment: @Paul H.. I had, but I am not sure.

Comment: All parts done; in python3. You might have to translate a few things.

Comment: Maybe the format isn't what you need, but the Meteorlogical Institute has monthly and yearly data available.
http://owww.met.hu/eghajlat/eghajlati_adatsorok/bp/Navig/202_EN.htm

Comment: @TimCera... yeah I saw it before. Thanks for your comment. But still I have a question even though the above code works. How can I write  dataFrame for it?